# Identify a strange 11-pin SCART connector

Tags: identification, connector, scart

I have stumbled upon a strange 11-pin SCART connector on a Chinese manufacturer's website. Its model name is **[ST342R-11](http://www.alextronic.biz/product%20types/scart%20socket.html)**. The photo and the mechanical drawing below are coming directly from the manufacturer:

[image: 11-pin SCART photo]
[image: 11-pin SCART mechanical dimensions]

I have never seen anything like this, so I started searching what such connector was used for. I couldn't find anything useful, not a single mention of such connector existence, and no traces of a plug that would fit to this socket. It would make sense to use this connector to create a uni-directional SCART or an audio-only SCART variants.

Was there any device using this connector? Is ST342R-11 a copy of a product by some well-known manufacturer? Maybe it is not SCART, but a completely different connector used for something other than AV equipment? Or maybe it's just a part of specification that was not widely adopted? Was any reduced pin count connectors specified in EN50049?

Surprisingly, some amount of SCART clipart depicts this 11-pin variant, but I am sure, the number of pins was halved as an artistic choice rather than depicting this exact connector. I also doubt that the Chinese manufacturer have based their product of a clipart design.

[image: SCART 11-pin clipart]

Comment: I wrote Alextronic and asked them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alextronic replied:

Dear Davide,
Per our development record, it is used for composite RGB signals.
It is a special connector which was developed according to a
customer special requirement but I do not know what kind of device is
applied.

Thanks a lot
Best Regards
Ryan Lin